# Implementing a trait for multiple types at once

Tags: rust

I have two structs and a trait:

```
struct A {
    x: u32,
}

struct B {
    x: u32,
}

trait T {
    fn double(&self) -> u32;
}
```

I would like to implement `T` for both structs using `x`.

Is there a way to write something like

```
impl T for A, B {
    fn double(&self) -> u32 {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

I would like to not use macros if possible.

Answer (score 35):

Creating a macro also solves your problem:

```
struct A {
    x: u32,
}

struct B {
    x: u32,
}

trait T {
    fn double(&self) -> u32;
}

macro_rules! impl_T {
    (for $($t:ty),+) => {
        $(impl T for $t {
            fn double(&self) -> u32 {
                self.x * 2
            }
        })*
    }
}

impl_T!(for A, B);

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 32):

The only way to implement a trait once for many concrete types is to implement a trait for all types already implementing another trait.

For example, you can implement a marker trait `Xed` and then:

```
impl<T> Double for T
where
    T: Xed,
{
    fn double(&self) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

**However**, Rust has principled generics. The only thing that you know about `T` in the previous implementation is that `T` implements the `Xed` `trait`, and therefore the only associated types/functions you can use are those coming from `Xed`.

A trait cannot expose a field/attribute, only associated types, constants and functions, so `Xed` would need a getter for `x` (which need not be called `x`).

If you wish to rely on *syntactic* (and not *semantic*) properties of the code, then use macros.

Comment: The thing is, I would like to access fields in my trait implementation. Hence the problem.

Comment: @jz87: Make a getter in the `Xed` trait or use a macro, as mentioned. There is no support for "mapping fields" in traits to Rust (and there may never be, as getters are sufficient).

Comment: Would there be a way to maintain that getter private while the other trait methods are public?

Comment: @eldruin: Trait methods are always public, but trait themselves can be private. To maintain the getter private you would implement either directly on the type (inherent method) or on a private trait.

Comment: For me this fails with `type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)` (even if the Trait `Xed` is local to the module).

Comment: @Florian: I... have no idea what you're talking about. If you can't find a solution to your problem, feel free to ask a question or hop in the [rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust).

Comment: @MatthieuM. The formatting got messed up. The problem was that I tried to implement a trait from another module and that does not work with a generic parameter because of the orphan rule. I'm using a macro now.

Answer (score 14):

Using [the `duplicate_item` attribute macro](https://crates.io/crates/duplicate) you can do the following:

```rust
use duplicate::duplicate_item;
#[duplicate_item(name; [A]; [B])]
impl T for name {
    fn double(&self) -> u32 {
        self.x * 2
    }
}
```

This will expand to two identical implementations for the two structs.
I know you said you didn't want to use macros, but I interpret that as meaning you don't want to roll your own macro, so I think this is a good compromise.

You could also use `duplicate_item` to avoid repeating your struct definitions:

```
use duplicate::duplicate_item;
#[duplicate_item(name; [A]; [B])]
struct name {
    x: u32,
}
```

Or go all-out if you for some reason need two identical structs with identical implements (at this point we should begin questioning why we need 2 structs at all :D):

```
use duplicate::duplicate;
duplicate!{
    [ name; [A]; [B] ]
    pub struct name {
        x: u32,
    }
    impl T for name {
        fn double(&self) -> u32 {
            self.x * 2
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the use of the `duplicate` function-like macro this time to duplicate struct and implement at the same time.

Comment: The first code block of your answer didn't work for me. Small tweak based on the crate documentation (https://docs.rs/duplicate/0.2.2/duplicate/):

A,B should each be enclosed in their own [] square brackets.

use duplicate::duplicate
#[duplicate(name; [A]; [B])]
impl T for name {...

Comment: This is great! Just what I needed for the thing I'm working on. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since the internals of your structs are the same / share common components, you should extract them into a common struct and embed the common part back into the parent structs. The common struct would have the "complicated" implementation of the trait and then the parent struct's trait implementations would delegate to the common implementation:

```
trait T {
    fn double(&self) -> u32;
}

struct A {
    common: Common,
}

impl T for A {
    fn double(&self) -> u32 {
        self.common.double()
    }
}

struct B {
    common: Common,
}

impl T for B {
    fn double(&self) -> u32 {
        self.common.double()
    }
}

struct Common {
    x: u32,
}

impl T for Common {
    fn double(&self) -> u32 {
        self.x * 2
    }
}
```

Any nicer code will require changes to the language. Two possible paths:

- [Fields in traits](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/fields-in-traits-rfc)
- [Delegation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393)

Answer (score 0):

There's this reference for doing [Default Implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#default-implementations).

It has the caveat that you will not use whatever is in `self` since we don't know what `self` is at this point, unless we call another method of the trait.

```rust
pub trait Summary {
    fn summarize(&self) -> String {
        String::from("(Read more...)")
    }
}

struct NewsArticle;

impl Summary for NewsArticle{}
```