# How can I implement a trait method once for multiple structs without defining methods to access the fields?

Tags: rust, polymorphism

I have two structs `A` and `B` that are similar and have overlapping behaviour. I defined a trait which both of the structs implement.

Both structs have the same field `a` and the method `is(&self)` defined in the trait has the exact same implementation in both struct, so I wanted to move the implementation to the trait, instead of having duplicate code in both structs.

However, the `is(&self)` method needs to access field `a` of `&self` for the calculation of the return value.

Here some example code of the problem:

```
trait T {
    fn is(&self) -> bool;
    // other methods
}

pub struct A {
    a: i32,
}

impl T for A {
    fn is(&self) -> bool {
        // This calculation is actually more complex
        self.a > 0
    }
    // other methods of T
}

pub struct B {
    a: i32,
    // more fields
}

impl T for B {
    fn is(&self) -> bool {
        // This calculation is actually more complex
        self.a > 0
    }
    // other methods of T, that are implemented differently from A's implementations
}
```

How can I implement the `is(&self)` method once for struct `A` and `B` without defining methods in the trait to access the field `a`?

Comment: You cannot. I believe this to be already answered by [Implementing a trait for multiple types at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39150216/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the exact differences.

Comment: I agree. Didn't find that question, here. Sorry for the duplicate and thank you for the comment.

Comment: There's no need to apologize for duplicates! Each duplicate leaves a signpost back to another question. Now this question will help people who phrased the question in the same way you did to find the right answer!

Comment: Maybe you could have each implement `trait HasA { fn getA(&mut self) -> &mut i32; }`, then implement `impl<T: HasA> T { fn is(&mut self); }`.  It's not quite the same thing but the logical structure is something like what you want.