# Duplicate trait method implementation in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

In the following code, the implementation of `show_author()` is the same for `Post` and `PostDraft`.

Is it possible to de-duplicate it and implement it directly in the trait, or in another form, so that it wouldn't have to be written twice?

```
trait PostAuthor {
    fn show_author(&self) -> String;
}

struct Post {
    author: String,
}

struct PostDraft {
    author: String,
}

impl PostAuthor for Post {
    fn show_author(&self) -> String {
        &self.author
    }
}

impl PostAuthor for PostDraft {
    fn show_author(&self) -> String {
        &self.author
    }
}
```

When trying to replace the method signature with the actual implementation in the trait, the following error shows, indicating that the trait obviously doesn't know (and rightly so) about any `author` field:

```
error: attempted to take value of method `author` on type `&Self`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:15
  |
5 |         &self.author
  |               ^^^^^^
  |
  = help: maybe a `()` to call it is missing? If not, try an anonymous function
```

In a hypothetical purposefully-invalid imaginary Rust code, a solution would be to simply declare the implementation for the two `struct`s at once:

```
impl PostAuthor for Post, PostDraft {
    fn show_author(&self) -> String {
        &self.author
    }
}
```

Comment: What differentiates a `Post` from a `PostDraft`?

Comment: I believe your question is already answered by the answers of [Implementing a trait for multiple types at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39150216/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this as already answered.

Comment: @Schwern in this example, absolutely nothing. In reality, they don't implement the same field definitions and/or method implementations. And there are more than two. The only rigorously common part is the `show_author` method, and it's more complicated IRL, therefore I'd like to avoid duplicating it.

Comment: @Shepmaster this was not the answer I was _hoping for_, but that was the actual answer indeed. Actually it makes sense, and as one of the answer mentions, the code above calls for refactoring. Thanks for your reactivity.

Comment: I feel like implementing `Post` and `PostDraft` as separate structs is the real problem here. "Draft" (or "published") might better be a trait.

Comment: @Schwern it makes sense — however I'm trying to follow the example from the Rust Book where they go through a variant of the state pattern using types as state, hence the two different types here — https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/second-edition/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html

Comment: @Schwern it is a duplicate as it is phrased; you'd need to perform substantial editing to make *this* not a duplicate. Perhaps you need to self-ask/answer a question that is phrased however you need it be to answer it.

Comment: @Schwern actually this part of the Rust Book is precisely about using several types to model state, instead of putting state in a given, unique type. I suggest you read through the link I provided if you're interested, as it gives quite a surprising perspective on that, at least as I found.

Comment: @Jivan I see where you're at in the example now. I think in this instance rather than adding more String fields to all the structs, you'd create a new struct like `struct Content { body: String, author: String }` and have everything use that. `struct DraftPost { content: Content }` and `struct Post { content: Content }`.

Comment: @Schwern that's exactly what I ended up doing — it seems to be the most natural way to do that, effectively