# Generating secure random bytes in rust

Tags: security, random, rust

I'm trying to use ring::rand::Secure/SystemRandom to generate some secure random bytes:

```
let mut randoms: [u8; 10] = [0; 10];
let sr = ring::rand::SystemRandom::new();
sr.fill(&randoms); // Error: fill method not found in `SystemRandom`
```

Now i'm not sure why SystemRandom doesn't implement 'fill' - there's a fair bit of indirection in the ring library but I believe it should:

Firstly, SystemRandom implements sealed::SecureRandom:

```
impl sealed::SecureRandom for SystemRandom {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn fill_impl(&self, dest: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(), error::Unspecified> {
        fill_impl(dest)
    }
}
```

Next, sealed::SecureRandom implements SecureRandom (i'm unsure why the need for generics here?):

```
impl<T> SecureRandom for T
where
    T: sealed::SecureRandom,
{
    #[inline(always)]
    fn fill(&self, dest: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(), error::Unspecified> {
        self.fill_impl(dest)
    }
}
```

And thus SystemRandom implements SecureRandom via the internal sealed::SecureRandom.

However it doesn't seem to compile, am i missing something important here?

Thanks

- edit -

Turns out i had `use ring::rand::SystemRandom` but needed to also have `use ring::rand::SecureRandom` to make that function visible.

Now my problem is:

```
sr.fill(&randoms);
|        ^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
```

Comment: "I'm unsure why the need for generics here?" `sealed::SecureRandom` is a trait, not a type. The generics are needed for a [blanket implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150216/implementing-a-trait-for-multiple-types-at-once) of `SecureRandom`. Essentially, it's saying: every type `T` that implements `sealed::SecureRandom` shall also implement `SecureRandom`, and here's how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fill` expects a [**mutable** reference](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/blob/432909280dfcb620bf23677f5d73286b345c3952/src/rand.rs#L41) to `randoms`. So just change

```
sr.fill(&randoms);
```

to

```
sr.fill(&mut randoms);
```